# xsl : Incrementing a global variable

Tags: xslt, global-variables, xslt-1.0, immutability

I know the fact that variables in XSL are immutable. But in my scenario, I want to increment a global variable and use the value later. Is there any other way by which this can be done? I have added enough comments in the code to make my question more clear. Please note I am using XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:variable name="counter">0</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:for-each select="Condition_ABC">
  <xsl:variable name="returnValue"> <!--returnValue is the return value from the named template GetValue -->
   <xsl:call-template name="GetValue"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:if test="not($returnValue= '')">
   <!-- If the returned value is not null
        Here I want to add the increment logic, something like this 
        $counter = $counter+ 1  -->
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="some_pattern">
 <Attribute>
  <!-- the final 'counter' value from above xsl block needs to be outputted here -->
  <xsl:value-of select="$counter"/>
 </Attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you want us to suggest an XSLT way of solving your problem you should post minimal but complete samples of XML input and corresponding output you want to create. Then we should be able to outline how to approach the problem with XSLT. You can use global variables in XSLT but you can only bind a value once and not change it later.

Comment: You are attempting to write procedural code in XSLT, which won't work. This is a common issue, and one of the reasons why people get frustrated and dislike XSLT. If you can describe the conditions/rules we can show you how to achieve the results with a different approach.

Comment: Simply replace the `xsl:for-each` instruction with a recursive call, passing as the value of the parameter `pCounter` the expression `$pCounter +1`. This is the general pattern of "incrementing"/"modifying" in a functional language.

Comment: Describe your problem, not your incorrect approach to solving it. If you tell us what your input is and your desired output, and make it clear how the output relates to the input, then we can tell you how to achieve it without mutable variables.